# Run scheduler using spring

Tags: spring, scheduling

I have rest api. A starttime is passed to this rest api. I want to schedule a job after that particular time. This job will run only once. My application where I need to add this feature runs as windows service. I have written some code but that is never scheduled. Please advise.

```
     @Component
    @Path("/appcheck")
    @Api(value = "/appcheck")
    public class ApplicationCheckImpl extends RestEndpoint
            implements ApplicationCheckApi  {
    @POST
        @Path("/check")
        @ApiOperation(value = "Check",notes = "Sample Check", response = java.lang.String.class)
        @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad values")})

        public Response checkApp(
                @ApiParam(value = "json", required = true)
                String src,
                @QueryParam("instances") Integer instances,
                @QueryParam("scheduleTime") Integer scheduleTime,
                @Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {


            if (scheduleTime != null) {
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                now.add(Calendar.MINUTE, scheduleTime);
                Date startTime = now.getTime();
                applicationCheckServiceApi.setStartTime(startTime);
                applicationCheckServiceApi.setInstances(instances);
                applicationCheckServiceApi.setScheduleTime(scheduleTime);
                applicationCheckServiceApi.setServletRequest(servletRequest);
                applicationCheckServiceApi.setSrc(src);

               AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
                ctx.register(ApplicationCheckConfiguration.class);
return applicationCheckServiceApi.getResponse();
    }
```

## ApplicationCheckConfiguration

```
 @Configuration
        @EnableScheduling
        @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.abc")
        public class ApplicationCheckConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {

            @Autowired
            private ApplicationCheckServiceApi applicationCheckServiceApi;

            @Override
            public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
                taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskScheduler());
                taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(
                        new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                myTask().work();
                            }
                        },
                        new Trigger() {
                            @Override public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                                return applicationCheckServiceApi.getStartTime();
                            }
                        }
                );
            }

            @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
            public Executor taskScheduler() {
                return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(42);
            }


            @Bean
            public MyTask myTask() {
                return new MyTask();
            }
        }
```